# jquery conflict with jquery cycle slider with fancybox

Tags: jquery

I have a site that uses a jQuery slider called "cycle." When you click on a slide a fancybox pops up. The slider then pauses which is correct, but what I need is for the slider to resume after the fancybox is closed. Essentially, I cannot get the second part of this code to function.

```
$('.fancy-box').click(function(){
console.log('pause is working')
$('.hero-carousel').cycle('pause');
});

$('.fancybox-close').click(function(){
console.log('resume is working');               
$('.hero-carousel').cycle('resume');
});
```

Comment: can you provide some relevant HTML please

Comment: Cant do much without seeing your HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a event delegate for the close button, just in case it gets build on the fly (and therefore doesn't exist on pageload yet):

```
$("body").on("click", ".fancybox-close", function(event){
    console.log('resume is working');               
    $('.hero-carousel').cycle('resume');
});
```

UPDATE:

Since this seemed to have fixed the issue, I want to explain what the issue was a little better (just in case somebody experiences the same problem in the future).

When the page gets loaded, there is no element with a class name of `fancybox-close`. Therefore, the click handler never gets attached to anything.

`$("body").on("click", ".fancybox-close", function(event){...});` will listen to any clicks that happen within the body tag (so pretty much every click) and if that click originated on an element that has a classname of `fancybox-close`, then it will execute the function.  Therefore we now are no longer dependent on the element being present on page load or not.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of HTML. Steve's code worked like charm. I knew that it was an issue with the fancybox and I didn't know how to replicate that functionality in jsfiddle.